# Rotate, Move, Scale Not Working

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I recently installed 2.80 to continue my work. Suddenly when I was working, keyboard shortcuts for Move (G), Rotate (R), Scale (S) stopped working. Every thing else works fine. I m using windows 7 64bit. Although 2.80 was working fine in Windows 10 64bit